# Use Raspberry Pi with SSH disabled and no access to the screen

Tags: ssh, gui, putty, accessibility

I recently reinstalled Debian Jessie on a Pi 3. When I turn it on the screen is blank and my keyboard does not light up - before the reinstall, the GUI would only start and the keyboard would light up if I restarted it with putty.

I cannot remember how I ever managed to get it operating at that point, I think it worked magically the first time and then stopped. Now I have realized that I cannot ssh into it. I am in some trouble here as I have to present a working OpenHAB2 system to my boss by the end of the day.

Please save me.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to enable SSH by plugging the SD card into my laptop and enabling SSH in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`.